# Неизвестная ошибка

Tags: php, javascript, css, mysql

Пытаюсь сделать вот такое меню ([смотреть меню](http://grimon.net/test_menu.php)). Вот код:

```
<?php
require_once "conf.php";
dbConnect();
?>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://grimon.net/css/jqueryslidemenu.css" />    
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://grimon.net/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://grimon.net/js/jqueryslidemenu.js"></script>
</head>
<div id="myslidemenu" class="jqueryslidemenu">  
<ul>
<?php
function menu($id) {
$zapros=mysql_query("select * from menu where Id_id={$id}") or die (mysql_error());
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($zapros)){
//echo "<div id="myslidemenu" class="jqueryslidemenu">";
//echo "<ul>"
echo "<li><a href='#'>{$row['name']}</a></li><ul>";
menu ($row['id']);
echo "</ul>";
}
}
echo "<ul>";
menu (0);
echo "</ul>";
?>
</div>
</ul>
```

В хроме вообще ничего не отображает, а мозилле показывает обычное меню. И совсем не динамическое. Хотя при просмотре кода страницы и в хроме, и в мозилле пишет:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://grimon.net/css/jqueryslidemenu.css" />    
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://grimon.net/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://grimon.net/js/jqueryslidemenu.js"></script>
</head>
<div id="myslidemenu" class="jqueryslidemenu">  
<ul>
<ul><li><a href='#'>Меню 1</a></li><ul><li><a href='#'>Меню 11</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href='#'>меню 22</a></li><ul></ul></ul></ul></div>
</ul>
```

В чем может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 2):

А мне стукнуться не судьба была, раз уж с моего сайта пример и юзаете? :-))) Освобожусь стукну в агент, покажу что у тебя не так. )) Выборка не совсем приемлимая и вид списка не правильный (по несколько ul подряд открыты - хром такое и не поймет).

И надо учитывать то, что если уж делаете обращения на каждый пункт, то делате 2 функции. Первая берет пункт, а вторая смотрит есть ли в нем подпункты. Но пока что я могу сказать одно - база для меню у вас не особо-то и корректно сделана.

Comment: тебя не было в сети

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
<ul><li><a href='#'>Меню 1</a></li><ul><li><a href='#'>Меню 11</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href='#'>меню 22</a></li><ul></ul></ul></ul>
```

Вам нужно немного по-другому. В таких меню на jquery необходимо, чтобы все подменю (`<ul>`) содержались в пункте его вызывавшем (li). Иначе теряется весь смысл. Т.е. надо добиться кода:

```
<ul><li><a href='#'>Меню 1</a><ul><li><a href='#'>Меню 11</a></li><li><a href='#'>меню 22</a></li></ul></li></ul>
```

**Добавлено.**

Что-то вроде этого:

```
<?php
function menu($id) {
$zapros=mysql_query("select * from menu where Id_id={$id}") or die (mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($zapros)){
echo "<ul>";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($zapros)){
echo "<li><a href='#'>{$row['name']}</a>";
menu ($row['id']);
echo "</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
return 1;
}
else return 0;
}

menu (0);

?>
```

Но опять же... Лучше сначала выбрать все записи из таблицы, а потом разбирать их с помощью php, чтобы не загружать скулевский сервер. На каждый ваш запрос к БД уходит много времени. Если к примеру ваше меню будут загружать одновременно 50 пользователей, то сервер просто задохнется... Опять же зависит от количества пунктов и от сервера, но зачем тратить лишний раз ресурсы сервера, которых итак обычно мало?..